# How to redirect uppercase requests to lowercase using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect urls like /BroWse/tiTLE to /browse/title, but exclude urls like /js/Ae2bDF.js

Currently I'm using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lower:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It can match the uppercase urls but redirect them to homepage, what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it because I forget to define `lower` filter.

I added

```
RewriteMap  lower int:tolower
```

to my apache conf file, then it start to work.

This RewriteMap can only be set in apache conf or virtual machine config file, 
RewriteRule can be in conf file or .htaccess file.